# Disable reorder of sap.ui.commons.Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5, accordion

I created an accordion according to [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/Accordion.html) and want to disable the possibility to reorder the sections by drag & drop. I don't see this option in the [API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.Accordion.html) and I'm not sure why this feature exist in the first place.

Thanks.

Comment: Having the same problem here... Would love to hear a solution.

Comment: Have you considered subclassing the Accordion? I looked at the code and there seems to be no single property to disable this feature.

Comment: Your suggestion can help, but in my case I wanted to use the control as it is, without changing the code. I wonder why SAP didn't give this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sorting is provided with the jQuery UI plugin : Sortable [http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/). I figured that sorting is enabled and disabled using two css classes: ui-sortable and ui-sortable-disabled. So, I added the 'ui-sortable-disabled' to my accordion to disable the sorting.
Code :

```
 oAccordion.onAfterRendering = function () {
                  this.addStyleClass('ui-sortable-disabled');
              }
```

Let me know if this resolved your issue.